# How can I append with aggregateByKey and limit the size to 10?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a RDD

```
[playerID, gameID, amount_played]
```

I want to group the playerID by key and only take 50 maximum for each playerID

```
RDD.aggregateByKey(\
                  0, # initial value for an accumulator \
                  lambda r, v: r + v, # function that adds a value to an accumulator \
                  lambda r1, r2: r1 + r2 # function that merges/combines two accumulators \
                 ).take(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using combine by key:

```
def appender(a,b):
    a.append(b)
    return a

def extender(a, b):
    a.extend(b)
    return a

recommendRDD.combineByKey(\
              lambda movieId: [movieId], #make a list of the initial value \
              appender,\ #the appender adds a movie to a pre-created list
              extender)\ # combines two pre-created lists
            .take(1)
```

If you need to limit the number of movies, you can just add logic to the `appender` and `extender` functions:

```
def appender(a,b):
    a.append(b)
    return a[:10]

def extender(a, b):
    a.extend(b)
    return a[:10]
```

But you need to be careful how you limit, because you might be excluding the highest-recommended movies.

Comment: I tried adding if len(extender < 10 : in the def methods but it didn't work

Comment: Edited. The best way to make sure you return the 10 highest-recommended movies for the user is to include a score and make these functions sort or anything that just takes it into account...

Comment: True, I have a score for them but the RDD is so big that I'm trying basic versions before I extend the whole calculation. Let's say I have a column, amount_times_watched what'd be the way to include a sort? The column refers to the movie being watched totally by all users.

Comment: what'd be the best way to sort it?

Comment: If you have a field by which you want to sort (say, `score`), then you can simply sort the content of the list before pulling the first 10 `a.sort(key = lambda l: l.score)` just before `return a[:10]`

Comment: def appender(a,b):
   a.sort(key = lambda l: l.score)  a.append(b)
    return a[:10]   --  Would it be like this?

Comment: @JayRons No. You should *append BEFORE you sort**

Comment: I actually had a list of 27K movies and before all this I took the top 250 most popular movies from that list. Do you think I still need to do the sorting? Because there are only 250 different movieIDs within the rdd and they are the top 250.

Comment: If you're collecting all possible movies, then there's of course no need to sort

Comment: No not all possible movies. Just the top 10 most popular. I'd probably just sort them anyway. Even if I took the top 250 the popularity could still differ, right?

Comment: Thank you greatly for your help!